# issue in virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, virtual-keyboard

i have a script which is for virtual keyboard, i am facing some problem while creating a keys for superscript and subscript.For eg. while i am using `<'sup'>3<'/sup'>` in my span class it displays it right,but when i am pressing that key it also prints `<'sup'>3<'/sup'>` in textbox.
so what should i need to change in jquery ?

Here is my working code.

**HTML CODE :**

```
    <li class="symbol"><span class="off"><sup>11</sup></span><span class="on"><sup>11</sup></span></li>
```

**JQuery CODE**

```
// Special characters
    if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
```

**Full Code :**

[jsfiddle.net/xMzVY](http://jsfiddle.net/xMzVY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('symbol'))
    character = $('span:visible', $(this)).html();
```

Comment: I saw it. But it seems to be okay. Perfect. What is the issue now? I am using Chrome!

Comment: Hey now I see a big 6, which when I enter, it says `<sub>6</sub>`, is that what is your problem?

Comment: Hoi!!! You are using `.val()`, which doesn't render HTML in a textarea. So, you need to convert it into unicode and then display. And while saving, you need to convert it back to HTML. As, if you use HTML tags inside the `textarea` it renders as is!!! :)

Comment: Okay so can u help me Please How to do this?

Comment: Just use it as `innerText`, or strip the HTML characters and send the text alone inside the `textarea`. But, my suggestion would be you can use a text previewer, like `MarkDown` and have both HTML version as well as rendered one! :)

Comment: Simple. Use MarkDown or TinyMCE to render and send Rich Text content.